# Querying for a missing key inside an array of objects in Postgres

Tags: json, postgresql

I am attempting to query json data inside a column that has an array of objects. I am attempting to look for a any json that has a key missing in one of the objects in the array

```
Example: 
    "groups": [{
                "id": "1234575",
                "name": "Lazer Tag team 1",
                "ranking": "1800"
            }, {
                "id": "5634378",
                "name": "Lazer Tag team 2"
                "ranking": 6002
            }, {
                "id": "7568493",
                "name": "Lazer Tag Team 3",
                "ranking": "3215"
            }
        ],
```

What I am trying to find is any Json that does not contain "name" within these objects

```
Example:


"groups": [{
                "id": "1234575",
                "name": "Lazer Tag team 1",
                "ranking": "1800"
            }, {
                "id": "5634378",
                "ranking": 6002
            }, {
                "id": "7568493",
                "name": "Lazer Tag Team 3",
                "ranking": "3215"
            }
        ],

In this instance this Json is missing "name" in one of the objects so I would like to see a list of all the Jsons that would have this.
```

I have attempted the following and get no luck:

```
 select id , JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(json_message->'payload'->'groups') as partyGroup
 from "notice" n 
 where not (partyGroup ? 'name')
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Did you get an error message?

Answer (score 1):

To find the objects that are missing the `name` property, use a `jsonb_array_elements` as a lateral table function:

```
SELECT n.id, partygroup
FROM "notice" n, jsonb_array_elements(n.json_message->'payload'->'groups') AS partygroup
WHERE NOT (partygroup ? 'name');
```

To find the rows that are containing any object without a `name` property in their `groups` array, use `jsonb_array_elements` in a subquery in the condition:

```
SELECT n.id, n.json_message->'payload'->'groups' AS "partyGroups"
FROM "notice" n
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM jsonb_array_elements(n.json_message->'payload'->'groups') AS partygroup
  WHERE NOT (partygroup ? 'name')
);
```

Alternatively, you can use a [json path expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH):

```
SELECT n.id, n.json_message->'payload'->'groups' AS "partyGroups"
FROM "notice" n
WHERE n.json_message @? 'strict $.payload.groups[*] ? (!exists(@.name))'
```